# Android sometimes returns null when initializing tts on Samsung devices

Tags: android

Sometimes returning null when initializing tts
But it only happens on Samsung devices
I also added the following to the manifest, but the result is the same

Can't catch error even with try catch

Do you have any way to solve this problem?
compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 30

```
<queries>
         <intent>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
         </intent>
</queries>
```

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
        {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
    }
});
```

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.setLanguage(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
```